# how get data from database by matching first two characters in a columns using like query or something else

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get data from database by matching first two characters or the characters appears before comma `,`

```
id | company_name | country_id | city_id | main_category
 -------------------------------------------------------
 1 | ABC          |   1        |  2      |  12,3,6
 2 | XYZ          |   1        |  2      |  1,12,9
```

what I want is to get the following results when the user input is `12` and if `12` exist in `main_category than` result should be shown but the `12` should be exits before the first comma or we can say the first two characters

```
id | company_name | country_id | city_id | main_category
     -------------------------------------------------------
     1 | ABC          |   1        |  2      |  12,3,6
```

Query I tried

```
$getResult = $companies->where([

            ["company_name", "LIKE", "%$keyword%"],
            ['main_category', "LIKE", "%$sector%"]

    ])->get();
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731120/eloquent-search-in-two-columns-using-like

Comment: Just fix your broken schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match query start from beginning and end with a comma, you can do the following-

```
$getResult = $compaies->where("company_name", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")->where('main_category', "LIKE", "$sector,%")->get();
```

Comment: But why would you? :-(

Comment: @Strawberry i didn't get your point, its what is asked here, isn't it?

Comment: Normalisation would appear to be a more sensible solution.

Comment: ow! yes it is but in this case i just try to solve his current problem. But he should make a better db structure as you said.